# Why are the names of generic types mangled in a .NET stack trace?

Tags: c#, generics, exception, stack-trace

I have an exception being thrown from a C# method, that takes a generic list as a paremeter.

```
private static void DoWork(List<ClassName> a)
{
}
```

When it throws an exception, the stack trace shows an `1 instead of the class name for the list. Why is this? This is what the stack trace has.

```
... 
at DoWork(List`1 a).
...
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason why is that the stack trace is generated by the CLR and not C#.  Hence it uses CLR type names vs. C# type names.

The type names given to generic types in metadata (in both C# and VB.Net) have the form TypeName`Number where

- TypeName: Name of the type in the abscence of generic parameters
- Number: Count of generic parameters on the type

This is also why it's legal to have several generic classes which the same name but differing numbers of generic parameters.  At a CLR level they have different type names.

Comment: Is there any way around this? Currently dealing with an error log and I can't pinpoint the source because of this problem.