# What does the `1 or `2 suffix mean for classes created by Microsoft?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, coding-style

I recently noticed the following line in an ASP.NET error stack trace

```
System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +264
```

What does the `` `2 `` in `` IDictionary`2 `` mean?

I also found other classes/files named like that in the [codeplex repository of ASP.NET MVC](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/70574)

Comment: Semi-duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369294/why-are-the-names-of-generic-types-mangled-in-a-net-stack-trace/1369303#1369303 Different question but same answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's to indicate generic parameters. For example take a look at this reflection code:

```
var type = typeof(Dictionary<string, string>).GetInterface("IDictionary`2");
```

Comment: And in particular, it shows the *number* of generic type parameters.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET this is valid:

```
class X<T>
{
}

class X<T, U>
{
}
```

The *number* of the generic parameters "changes" the name of the class. So the number you see is the number of parameters (to use simpler words: classes/interfaces/structs can be "overloaded" on the number of generic parameters, so you can have `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`.)

These classes would be called `` X`1 `` and `` X`2 ``, and you would have

```
typeof(X<>).Name == "X`1";
typeof(X<,>).Name == "X`2";
```

Note that the *name* of the generic parameters doesn't "change" the name of the class. After the previous two definitions, this one would be invalid:

```
class X<U>
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The official function description is:

```
public override object Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
```

As you can see the type is `IDictioray<,>` Th '2 is the textual description of a generic taking 2 Types. List'1 for example is a List<>