# Reflection, get types that implement an interface, but don't implement another one

Tags: c#, reflection

I've got two types of repository classes in my API:

Those with both IRepository and IReportRepository:

```
internal class BuildingRepository : IBuildingRepository
public interface IBuildingRepository : IRepository<Building>, IReportRepository<BuildingReport>
```

And those with just IRepository:

```
internal class AppointmentRepository : IAppointmentRepository
public interface IAppointmentRepository : IRepository<Appointment>
```

How can I return all repositories that only implement IRepository and not IReportRepository. I thought it would be something like this:

```
var repoInterfaceType = typeof(IRepository<>);
var reportRepo = typeof(IReportRepository<>);
var repoTypes = asm.GetTypes().Where(x =>
            !x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract && x.IsClass && 
            !x.IsGenericType && x.GetInterfaces().Any(y =>
                y.IsGenericType &&
                repoInterfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(y.GetGenericTypeDefinition()) && 
      !reportRepo.IsAssignableFrom(y.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))).ToList();
```

But it is still returning me both. What am I missing?

Comment: You have written code that you can no longer debug.  Standard programming hazard.  Asking somebody else to debug it for you only ever really works when you give a concrete example.  Consider using less && operators in a single statement to get ahead, it is quite okay to have more variables to put in a Watch expression.  The machine doesn't mind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can greatly shorten the code using [GetInterface(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayfa0fcd(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var results = asm.GetTypes()
    .Where
    (
        t => t.GetInterface("IRepository`1") != null
          && t.GetInterface("IReportRepository`1") == null
    );
```

This LINQ will iterate over all types and attempt to retrieve the two interfaces of interest. If the interface can't be found, only null will be returned, so we just need to check that the right one is null and the other one isn't.

In case you are wondering where I got the string "IReportRepository`1", this is known as the [mangled name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369294/why-are-the-names-of-generic-types-mangled-in-a-net-stack-trace), which is the string the CLR uses internally (you may recognize it from stack dumps). If you don't feel comfortable using a string literal, you can get it at runtime from the type's Name property, e.g.

```
var mangledName = typeof(IReportRepository<>).Name;
```

Comment: Hey that's quite easier, thanks, and yeah I know about the type mangling, I just had to do deal with that for some code generation also in the same code block I am using this, seems so silly!

Answer (score 1):

Your `.Any(y =>
                y.IsGenericType &&
                repoInterfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(y.GetGenericTypeDefinition()) && 
      !reportRepo.IsAssignableFrom(y.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))` parts must be split two queries. Because, `BuildingRepository` class is implementation of `IRepository<Building>`. This interface is assignable from `IRepository<>` and not assignable from `IReport<>` interface. Your `Any` condition return true in this case.

Your Linq can be modified like:

```
var repoTypes = asm.GetTypes().Where(x =>
                                         !x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract && x.IsClass &&
                                         !x.IsGenericType &&
                                         x.GetInterfaces().All(y => !y.IsGenericType || !reportRepo.IsAssignableFrom(y.GetGenericTypeDefinition())) &&
                                         x.GetInterfaces().Any(y => y.IsGenericType &&
                                                                    repoInterfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(y.GetGenericTypeDefinition())))
                   .ToList();
```